# linux and audio after su'ing to different user

Tags: linux, audio, permissions, liquidsoap

I have a 3rd party program that I run under a specially created user in linux (Ubuntu). I've noticed that it can't connect to ALSA and also gives me the following error:

> 2011/01/12 20:52:38 [ao:3] Opening
>   Advanced Linux Sound Architecture
>   (ALSA) output (2 channels)... No
>   protocol specified
>   xcb_connection_has_error() returned
>   true

The program in question is liquidsoap, and is a headless (no gui) audio streaming program/

However, when I try running the program under the default user account, everything works fine. My question is, is this a permissions problem? And if so, where would I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
$ sudo adduser <user> audio
$ sudo adduser <user> pulse
$ sudo adduser <user> pulse-access
```

Comment: adding them to just the audio group did the trick. Although I have noticed only one user can access the audio device at any given moment. Is this intended behaviour?